# What does "tellus" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

What does  the word *tellus* mean? In the research sites we see the word "Earth" as meaning, but there is an article that cites the Latin word as "sense of the way of man".

Comment: Can you cite the article?

Comment: I agree with @C.M.Weimer: It would be very useful to cite the source of the translation "sense of the way of man". That would also help us give a more tailored answer.

Comment: Apart from the fact that "sense of the way of man" is meaningless in English.

Comment: @fdb It could have been a mistaken reading, but of course given this was a drive-by question, it's probably some nonsense article read by someone without any real interest in the topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Tellūs, tellūris* is a rather poetic word meaning "earth", both in the sense of "soil" and in the sense of "the globe". Sometimes it's used like the Greek *Gaea* to mean a personification of the Earth. I've never heard of it meaning a "sense of the way of man".

For more information, see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tellus#Latin) (less reliable) or [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtellus) (more reliable).